# SQL: During DST, Midnight value of Local time (CST) needs to be 00:00:00 instead of 01:00:00

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, clr

I am trying to get some values for past 1 year from database precisely at midnight. But when daylight time saving began in march, my local Timestamp changes from 00:00:00 to 01:00:00. I am not sure how to deal with this, any suggestions. I am very new at sql, pardon me if its a simple question. My code:

```
    DECLARE @host nvarchar(20)
    DECLARE @startTime  datetime
    DECLARE @endTime datetime
    DECLARE @quality nvarchar(20)

    DECLARE @sampleType nvarchar(20)

    set @host = 'localhost'

    set @startTime = DATEADD(MONTH, -12,  DATEDIFF(d, 0, GetDate())) 

    set @endTime = DATEADD(MONTH, 0,  DATEDIFF(d, 0, GetDate())) 

    set @quality = 'all' -- good,bad,uncertain

    set @sampleType = 'TimeAverage' -- average

     SELECT * FROM [VantagePointCLR].[dbo].[HistoryWithAggregationTimeBased]

     (

     'System.Sources.Simulator.ExtruderData1.Tags',

     '.BatchNumber',      

     (@startTime ),

     (@endTime),

     @sampleType,  

     86400000,   -- milliseconds in 1 day

      1,            -- true [0 = false]

      @quality,

      @host)
```

Comment: That looks like a TVF, which means we dont' have your code at all here. Is DST an issue through the period of it or just that day? Either way, I would create a table with details of the dates that DST starts and end, then you'll need to do some datetime manipulation on your column to take 1 hour away if the date appears between the dates of DST. Without further detail though, there's little more to offer; as we don't have the actual `SELECT` statement for your query, or any sample data.

Comment: The good news is, it looks like you're using CLR, which is probably going to be easier than doing this in SQL.

Comment: DST is issue for entire period (2nd Sunday of Mar to 1st sunday of Nov).